# OpenCv: Cant open capture object for Kinect

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, openni

I have installed OpenNI and SensorKinect following the tutorial [here](http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-kinect-openni-primesense/):  and the example viewer works just fine. I have downloaded OpenCV 2.4.3 and then done the following:

1. mkdir release
2. cd release
3. cmake-gui ..
4. hit configure
5. set WITH_OPENNI to ticked
6. checked that it has found OPENNI dirs and primesense dir
7. hit configure and then generate
8. ran make

I then try and run the sample code from OpenCV-2.4.3/samples/openni_capture.cpp

However I get the following output:

```
Device opening ...
done.
Can not open a capture object.
```

The relevant code is:

```
VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
if( isVideoReading )
    capture.open( filename );
else
    capture.open( CV_CAP_OPENNI );

cout << "done." << endl;

if( !capture.isOpened() )
{
    cout << "Can not open a capture object." << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: just some obvious questions: is the kinect connected and also powered ? Have you tried it without the opencv/openni bindings (e.g. do the OpenNI samples run, etc.) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Kinect is connected and powered. Yes, the openni samples run, I even compiled them myself and ran them. Just the openCV  examples wont

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had the same problem.

I solved it by installing the [SensorKinect driver](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/) again (something went wrong the first time) and then I installed OpenCV 2.4.3 like you described:

```
mkdir release
cd release
cmake-gui ..
hit configure
enabled WITH_OPENNI
hit configure and then generate
ran sudo make
```

I had to run `make` with `sudo`, otherwise I was getting errors all the time.

AND at the end you have to do

```
sudo make install
```

I mean, that's the meaning of the whole procedure above, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put this debugging line, `cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;`, in your code, right before

`if( !capture.isOpened() )
    {
        cout << "Can not open a capture object." << endl;
        return -1;
    }`

That will let you know if your opencv is installed with openni. If switches,

`OpenNI:                      YES (ver 1.5.4, build 0)
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  YES (/usr/lib/libXnCore.so)`

are `NO` in your case, then you might want to consider recompiling your opencv modules with the `cmake` flag `-D WITH_OPENNI=ON`.

Cheers!